# How can you have a Repository with dynamic data-sources?

Tags: design, design-patterns, repository, model, factory

Usually the Repository pattern looks like : 
[image]

What would be the best practice to make the repository handle more gateways (for Cache Redis, FTS/filtering Elasticsearch, Db Mysql etc.)

My ideas so far are to make a Repository array class that will loop through each repository when calling a method.

Also where would I implement the update/delete to remove from all the data sources?

Comment: Do you really have multiple data sources at *runtime*? Or do you just have multiple implementations where just one is used based on some configuration?

Comment: yes you have more at runtime, you have a cache, a db and a filtering engine for now, and it might extend

Comment: or maybe I got it wrong, my task says : The DataRepository is responsible to talk to the different data sources, and for that reason it needs
to be able to talk to a new data source with minimal additions to the code.
It also needs to be able to select which data sources is going to communicate with (in other words, the
data sources should be able to be added/removed dynamically).

Comment: Do you always need to check all of them, or do you check them in some order, only checking the next one if it wasn't already found?

Comment: well in practice when selecting by id I'm guessing you first look to the cache and then the db and there would be no need to query the search-engine (ES). When searching you just query the search-engine. When deleting/updating you should remove/update all, if they exist in their data-source.

Comment: Then, for queries you want a [Chain of Command](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). But since you need to act on all repositories on delete, you need to do as you said and try to update all datasources for updates. I'd wrap all your repositories in a facade repository to make sure they all get updated. Much like you mentioned. I think you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

Consider implementing special gateway implementation handling access to multiple other gateways (e.g. by looping as you wrote).
It will be more clear and flexible like handling that inside repository. 
Such gateway can also hide cluster transparently.

Comment: So it would be like a super-Gateway?

Comment: But then the gateways would have to return data in the same way in order to be compatible with the same logic used to build your domain object (in the factory)

Comment: yes it should follow same object structure but i think it is advantage of that as at the end you need objects as from the other gateways.